# Protractor - getText() returns an Array instead of a String

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I've got a fairly simple Protractor test which should check the text value in a row of a ng-repeat.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="destination in destinations">
    <span>{{destination.city}}, {{destination.country}}</span>
</div>
```

And here's my JS:

```
lastDestination = element.all(by.repeater('destination in destinations').row(1));
expect(lastDestination.getText()).toEqual("Madrid, Spain");
```

The [documentation for getText()](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) states:

> Get the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element, including sub-elements, without any leading or trailing whitespace.

So I'd expect the text from the row's span tag to be returned, but when running the Protractor test, I get the following error for the assertion:

**Expected [ 'Madrid, Spain' ] to equal 'Madrid, Spain'.**

GetText() seems to be returning an array instead of a string.

I tried resolving getText()'s promised, but still got the same error:

```
lastDestination = element.all(by.repeater('destination in destinations').row(1));

lastDestination.getText().then(function (text) {
   expect(text).toEqual("Madrid, Spain"); 
});
```

I can get around the issue by targeting the first value in the array:

```
expect(text[0]).toEqual("Madrid, Spain");
```

But I'd still like to know why this isn't working in the first place.

Any ideas?

**Update**: A [similar bug has been reported](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1794) on Protractor's Github page, so it could be that the getText() function is just not working as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the documentation:

```
// Returns a promise that resolves to an array of WebElements containing
// the DIVs for the second book.
bookInfo = element.all(by.repeater('book in library').row(1));
```

You are attempting to use getText on a promise, you need to resolve it first.

```
var lastDestination;
element.all(by.repeater('destination in destinations').row(1)).then(
     function(elements){
          lastDestination = elements[0];
});
expect(lastDestination.getText()).toEqual("Madrid, Spain");
```

SOURCE:http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater

This is what happens behind the scenes. Presuming you call getText() on an `WebElement` class. The `element` will be the value passed to the `core.text.getElementText`

Selenium(protractor) handles what parameters to send.

This is the code that gets the content, if a WebElement is used. I don't know what happens if a promise that resolves to an array is the explicit thisArg.

```
explicitThisArg.getText()//the explicit thisArg is the object that the function is called from.

  core.text.getElementText = function(element) {
  var text = '';
  var isRecentFirefox =
      (goog.userAgent.GECKO && goog.userAgent.VERSION >= '1.8');

  if (isRecentFirefox || goog.userAgent.WEBKIT || goog.userAgent.IE) {
    text = core.text.getTextContent_(element, false);
  } else {
    if (element.textContent) {
      text = element.textContent;
    } else {
      if (element.innerText) {
        text = element.innerText;
      }
    }
  }

  text = core.text.normalizeNewlines_(text);
  text = core.text.normalizeSpaces_(text);

  return goog.string.trim(text);
};
```

Comment: Your code works, however, the documentation for getText() states that "Get the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element, including sub-elements, without any leading or trailing whitespace". So I believe that getText() on the row should also work. I've found a similar issue here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1794, so I'm thinking this might be a bug.

Comment: I should note that you calling getText on a promise, which is not the documentations intended use anyway.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for delving into this and the detailed answer :)